# Is posible get the values from react-stripe-elements to display it in react-credit-cards component

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I would like to use the security and functionalities provided by [react-stripe-elements](https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-elements), but show it as the data is entered in the [react-credit-cards](https://github.com/amarofashion/react-credit-cards)  component. For this I would need to access the values that these fields would have. So it looked something like this:

[image]

How can I access the values entered in CardNumberElement, CardExpiryElement, CardCVCElement, etc. to show them in the visual component?

Is this posible? Thx in advance.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what specific features you are looking for? Your description is a little too general to really provide specific advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

This is not possible. You must provide CSS selectors to Elements for where your sensitive inputs (credit card number, expiration date and cvc) are to be displayed on your page, and then Stripe injects an iframe into your page to create each input. You cannot access the contents of these iframes from your code.

From the [Stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/cards/collecting/web#create-form):

> To securely collect card details from your customers, Elements creates UI components for you that are hosted by Stripe. They are then placed into your payment form, rather than you creating them directly.

Not being able to access this data is actually a *very good thing*. There are strict and complex regulations around direct handling of credit card data, with hefty fines for failing to meet them ([PCI compliance](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/)).

That being said, it *is* possible to customize the appearance of Stripe's injected inputs with CSS. See their [custom styles](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#stripe-elements) docs for more details. I've found this to meet my use cases for making custom forms. You could potentially leverage some of the CSS of a design you like from the react-credit-cards library you linked.

Finally, Stripe provides their own React library that might meet your use case or at least serve as a good starting point to apply your own customizations: [react-stripe-elements](https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-elements).